How to use fourier transform in PDE
I’m trying to understand the Fourier transform in the context of PDE. I can follow most of the calculation and proofs, but I have come up with some “weird” cases and I’d like some clarification.
I know that :

$S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the space of $C^\infty$ function that are rapidly decreasing . It’s called Schwarz space .

The Fourier transform is an isomorphism from $S(\mathbb R^n)$ to $S(\mathbb R^n)$

It turns derivative into multiplication


Consider the problem in 2 dimensions : $\Delta u=0$ and $u(x,0)=f(x)$ .
Consider the following approaches:
First method: Take the partial Fourier transform:
$$u(\xi,y)=\int_{\mathbb R} u(x,y) e^{-i\xi x} \, dx.$$
Solve the ODE in the “$y$” variable , take the inverse of the partial transform. I know this gives the correct result
Second method: Take the full transformation
$$u(\xi,\mu) = \int_{\mathbb R} u(x,y) e^{-i\xi x-i\mu y} \, dx \, dy.$$
The PDE becomes:
$$-\xi^2 u (\xi,\mu)-\mu^2 u(\xi,\mu)=0 \implies u(\xi,\mu)=0 \implies  u(x,y)=0.$$
I seek an explanation of why the first method works and second fails. Here are some of my attempts at explaining :
The reason for the second method failure is that the only function in $S(\mathbb R^n)$ satisfyng $\Delta u=0$ is the constant function $0$.
The reason for the first method's success is: $\forall y\in \mathbb R$ we have $u(\bullet,y)\in S(\mathbb R)$ . Thus we can apply the transform and its inverse for the first variable.

I notice that in neither situation the boundary conditions are considered. I think that the location and orientation of the boundary conditions of supremely important in finding a unique solution

The implication $(\xi^{2} + \mu^2)\hat{u} = 0 \implies \hat{u} = 0$ is not correct, unless you restrict to some subclass of distributions. Really what you can deduce is that $\hat{u}$ is supported at ${0}$, and by some distribution theory, this implies $u$ is a polynomial.


The reason for the second method failure is that the only function in $S(\mathbb R^n)$ satisfyng $\Delta u=0$ is the constant function $0$.

There are however other functions and function-like objects that are Fourier transformable.
To begin with, $f \in L^1$ is Fourier transformable simply by
$$\hat f(\xi) = \int f(x) \, e^{-i\xi\cdot x} \, dx.$$
Then it can be shown that if $f\in L^1 \cap L^2$ then $\hat f\in L^2.$ Based on this (and some related results) we can extend the Fourier transform to $L^2.$
But the Fourier transform can even be extended to functions like $\sin x$ and $x^2$ which are tempered distributions.
So why don't we get a solution within these spaces when we transform in all variables? The reason is simple: there are no solutions in these spaces either, not even in the space of tempered distributions.
There are non-trivial solutions that are not in these spaces, for example $u(x,y) = \sin x \ e^{-y}.$ This solution is not a tempered distribution because it grows too fast as $y\to -\infty.$
